# Swift 4 push is not working in Storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to push a VC to different VC. Till this date, I have worked a lot with `.xib` files. So, now moving to storyboard I am facing a little problem. I have two storyboards `A.storyboard` and `B.storyboard`

What I have tried is this:

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboard, bundle: nil)

let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboardId) 

controller.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This works fine for me, but I am worried about memory leakage. The other way which I know and prefer is this:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(LoginController(), animated: true)
```

But, when I use this ^ I get a black screen and nothing. Why the push is not working here, but works fine for me in `.xibs`?

Comment: Can you check self.navigationController is not nil?

Comment: _" I am worried about memory leakage"_… why? Are you seeing memory leaks?

Comment: Is LoginController with nib file or inside storyboard ?

Comment: Inside storyboard

Comment: @AshleyMills Nope, I am not seeing any, but I do not know which one is best. I am worried that they will stack up like one on another instead of one at a time.

Comment: So, initialize it with storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboardId)

Comment: @CRDave Not Nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code is correct, but it is not a push — it is a present. So you should change your code, like this:

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboard, bundle: nil)
let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboardId) 
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The problem with the second code is that `LoginController()` is not the login controller in the storyboard — it's just a new blank LoginController.

Comment: Ok got it. It is working, but on the next page, I can see a `Navigation Bar` with a `< Back` Bar button item. Can I remove the navigation bar?

Comment: You are the one who said you wanted to push. Your first sentence is: "I am trying to push a VC to different VC". A push involves a navigation controller. A navigation controller has a navigation bar and a back bar. We are doing what you said you wanted to do.

Comment: Is there a way to move to the next view controller without navigation bar?

Comment: "Move to"? Yes, that would be `present` — what you had in your first code. You said it was working, but you also said that for some reason you didn't like it. I never understood what you didn't like about it, but you said you wanted to push instead, so that's what I answered. If you like what your first code did, just keep it.

Comment: Thanks for your help.